# Add a class to a webkit input

Tags: html, css

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;

}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;

}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;
}
```

Hi,

The above is too general for me and I am not sure how I would add the `.inputFooter` class to the placeholder input. This is because the placeholder needs two different color at two instances, hence I cant have a general rule that applies to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the class at the beginning .
Note: changed the color to red to make easy to see

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/31edcwL1/)**

```
.inputFooter::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;
}

.inputFooter:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;

}

.inputFooter::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;

}

.inputFooter:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-top: none;
}
```